# Add series programmatically to an OxyPlot defined in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I'm testing OxyPlot for a project where users can drop datas on a graph.

I try to add series programmatically to an OxyPlot like this, but its not working :

```
<Grid>
    <oxy:Plot x:Name="TestPlot" Title="" AllowDrop="True">

    </oxy:Plot>
</Grid>
```

On Drop event function:

```
        OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries ls = new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries();
        ls.StrokeThickness = 1;

        OxyPlot.Wpf.Axis Xaxis = new OxyPlot.Wpf.LinearAxis();
        Xaxis.Maximum = 0;
        Xaxis.Minimum = 50;
        Xaxis.Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom;
        Xaxis.Title = "time";
        TestPlot.Axes.Add(Xaxis);

        OxyPlot.Wpf.Axis Yaxis = new OxyPlot.Wpf.LinearAxis();
        Xaxis.Maximum = 0;
        Xaxis.Minimum = 500;
        Xaxis.Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Left;
        Xaxis.Title = "Value";
        TestPlot.Axes.Add(Yaxis);

        ls.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 1));
        ls.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 100));
        ls.Points.Add(new DataPoint(20, 200));
        ls.Points.Add(new DataPoint(30, 300));

        TestPlot.ActualModel.Series.Add(ls);

        TestPlot.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

But the LineSerie isn't displayed. 
I'm missing somethind but can't figure out what when I googled this issue...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the drop event triggered at all?

Comment: Yes it is trigged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `Plot` element you should create a `OxyPlot.Wpf.LineSeries` and sets its `ItemsSource`:

```
OxyPlot.Wpf.LineSeries ls = new OxyPlot.Wpf.LineSeries();
ls.StrokeThickness = 1;
...
List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();
dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(0, 1));
dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(10, 100));
dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(20, 200));
dataPoints.Add(new DataPoint(30, 300));
ls.ItemsSource = dataPoints;

TestPlot.Series.Add(ls);
```